# Angular 4 instead of bootstrap 4 alpha version which can use

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I have try to use bootstrap in my new angular 4 Project. while I install bootstrap with npm i got bootstrap Alpha version get installed but my client not want use any Alpha version

So in Angular 4 instead of bootstrap Alpha Version which will use please suggest. without any npm install

Comment: Bootstrap 4 is currently in development. If you want a stable release. Choose bootstrap 3.

Comment: thanks Radouane, how to include without install npm

Comment: You can download the source a put them into assets and import them in your angular.cli or style.css but this is not the best practice... npm install is a better solution to manage versioning

Comment: this tried not work proper.. But while install npm always get Alpha version file

Comment: You have to specify the version you want `npm install bootstrap@3.3.7`

Comment: okay thanks its working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Radouane said, you can specify a version when you install packages via NPM.
So you can use: `npm install bootstrap@3.3.7` to get specifically the version 3.3.7.

Otherwise you can download the Bootstrap files and include them in your `index.html` file's header.

Finally you can use CDNs and inculde it, again, in the header of your `index.html` file:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>  
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`
```